# Como ler a linha de comando?

Tags: c, c++

Vamos dizer que eu queira fazer uma rotina para automatizar o processo de compilação de um programa. No geral (independente da linguagem), você chama compilador pela linha de comando. Por exemplo:

> javac meuPrograma.class

ou

> gcc meuPrograma.c -o meuPrograma

No Windows, podemos usar `system()`. Mas como ler a linha de comando ? No caso de um compilador, por exemplo, como ler os possíveis erros retornados pelo compilador na linha de comando. Melhor dizendo, como as IDEs fazem isso ? Isso seria importante se desejássemos integrar qualquer programa com interface CLI ao nosso sistema, não apenas para compiladores.

Comment: A IDE do Dev-C++ é um ótimo exemplo dessa integração CLI. Ela faz uso de utilitários padrões tais como o `gcc`, o `gdb` e o `make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O melhor é colocar os dois processos (seus dois programas) para conversarem entre si. Pode ser de várias formas diferentes, por exemplo: arquivo, memória compartilhada, mensagens ou socket.

Como você mencionou console do Windows, uma solução possível nesse caso é redirecionar a saída do console para um arquivo e depois imprimir isso no console.

Sua chamada do sistema ficaria mais ou menos com essa cara:

```
gcc meuPrograma.c -o meuPrograma > arquivo.txt | type arquivo.txt
```

Assim, seu próximo programa poderia ler esse arquivo.txt também.

Answer (score 6):

Queres obter o resultado de `system()` dentro do teu programa?
Usa  [`POSIX popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)  ou  [`MSDN _popen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b(v=vs.140).aspx)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *handle;
    char cmd[] = "dir";
    char line[1000];
    int n = 0;

    handle = popen(cmd, "r"); // se der erro de linker experimenta _popen
    if (!handle) {
        perror("");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, handle)) {
        printf("%03d: %s", ++n, line); // line includes ENTER
    }
    pclose(handle); // se der erro experimenta _pclose
}
```